# Distribution of charge on isolated system?

Tags: electrostatics

An isolated solid metallic sphere is charged with +Q. What will be the distribution of their +Q charge on the sphere ?

If it is conducting then the net charge resides on surface and if not the net charge is equally distributed through out the body . What does an isolated metallic sphere refer to ?

Comment: Metallic objects are generally conducting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Isolated metallic sphere*" here means that there are no external E-fields acting on the sphere.

Note that if the sphere weren't conducting, then you couldn't have guessed the distribution, it may be throughout the body,or on the surface, or in a portion of the body...